# How to make the first accordion tab open and the rest closed in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue in incrementing the `class="accordion-collapse collapse show` so that the first accordion tab should open and the closed. This is how I have done`class="accordion-collapse collapse '.if($i++){.'show'.}.'"` . I am do it in a while loop.

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="accordion-item">';
            echo ' <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-heading'.get_the_ID().'">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapse'.get_the_ID().'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapse'.get_the_ID().'">'
                      . get_the_title() . '
                    </button>
                  </h2>';
            echo '<div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse'.get_the_ID().'" class="accordion-collapse collapse '.($i++.'show'.).'"       aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-heading'.get_the_ID().'">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                  '
                      .the_content() . '
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
```

I am expecting the first according to open and the rest closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-
EDITED.

```
<?php

$flag = true;
if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">';
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $show_class = $flag == true ? 'show' : '';
        $collapsed = $flag == true ? '' : 'collapsed';
        echo '<div class="accordion-item">';
        echo ' <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-heading' . get_the_ID() . '">
                    <button class="accordion-button '.$collapsed.'" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapse' . get_the_ID() . '" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapse' . get_the_ID() . '">'
            . get_the_title() . '
                    </button>
                  </h2>';
        echo '<div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse' . get_the_ID() . '" class="accordion-collapse collapse ' . $show_class . ' "       aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-heading' . get_the_ID() . '">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                  '
            . the_content() . '
                  </div>
                </div>';
            $flag = false;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: we can use a true , false flag to check whether it's first accordion or not then add class `collapsed` and `show`.  See example above.